# TypeScript - Get max value from a mixed array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of arrays and I would like to find the max value of the first elements in those arrays.

Example:

```
[ [ 300, 600 ], [ 160, 600 ], [ 120, 600 ] ]
```

This example should return **300** because it is the **max value of 300, 160 and 120**.

This is an easy task and can be solved like this:

```
let first = array.map(item => item[0]);
let max = Math.max(...first); // max == 300
```

The problem is that I work with **TypeScript** and this array potentially can have a fixed string in it like so:

```
[ 'something' ]
```

No matter what I try to do I get errors from different places. For example I try something like this:

```
array.filter(item => item != "something").map(item => item[0]);
```

I cannot change the original array. So how can I overcome this issue with TypeScript? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Filter out only `number` values using **isNaN** after getting the list of first values from array inside the array

```js
let first = array.map(item => item[0]).filter(val => !isNaN(val));
```

Then perform `Math.max` on the resulted array

```
let max = Math.max(...first);
```

Comment: TS2345: Argument of type 'ReactText' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Is this error because of adding the code in answer to your app? Or is it the error raised because of subsequent lines/elsewhere in code?

Comment: Error might be because of changing the name of variable. Updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter array like this:

```js
const array = [[300, 600], [160, 600], [120, 600], ["something"]];
let first = array
  .filter(item => !isNaN(Number(item[0])))
  .map(item => Number(item[0]));
let max = Math.max(...first);

console.log('Max', max);
```

When `item[0]` is not a number `Number()` returns `NaN` that is filtered out by checking `!isNaN(Number(item[0]))`.

Comment: I like this one but when it deals with the string it returns "-Infinity"

Comment: Could you post an example of array you filtering?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that `filter` and `map` methods are immutable and do not change the original array.
There should be no problem with this snippet:

```
const max = Math.max(...(array
  .filter(item => item !== "sth")
  .map(item => item[0])
));
```

Comment: TS2345: Argument of type 'ReactText' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: You can assign filtered array a tuple type of (number, number). it ensures typescript that all items are arrays with your map requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can change map function to map strings to integer min so that they do not affect your max calculations

```
let first = array.map(item => typeof(item[0]) !== "string" ? item[0] : Number.MIN_VALUE);
let max = Math.max(...first); // max == 300
```