# Type Array is not assignable to number

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter, dice

I am trying to get the highest number from 5 dice. I call pips as eyes in this code. Here's my code:

```
// get the highest count
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098129/typescript-get-max-value-from-a-mixed-array
  getHighestNumber(dice: Die[]): number {
    return dice.reduce(
      (a: number, b: any, i: number, arr: any[]) =>
        arr.filter(x => x.eyes === a).length >=
        arr.filter(x => x.eyes === b.eyes).length ? a : b.eyes, null);
  }
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
Type 'Die' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: Die, currentValue: Die, currentIndex: number, array: Die[]) => Die, initialValue: Die): Die', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(a: number, b: any, i: number, arr: any[]) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: Die, currentValue: Die, currentIndex: number, array: Die[]) => Die'.
      Types of parameters 'a' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
        Type 'Die' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: Die, currentIndex: number, array: Die[]) => number, initialValue: number): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2769)
```

How do you fix this primitive logic? It's for a dice game called Yathzee and I'm developing it using the latest stable TypeScript version and newest stable Angular version.

I've tried the quick fix, which for some reason adds an underscore for i, didn't help, setting the type for b didn't help either...

My die data model looks like this:

```
export interface Die {
    eyes: number;
    locked: boolean;
}
```

Comment: You're declaring `a` to be `number` but passing `null` as initial value (which will be the first `a`). This doesn't seem right.

Comment: @VLAZ that's a good point. Should I initialize it as 1 or what would be the correct logic?

Comment: It *is* what the error message is telling you. As for what to initalise it as - `0` seems nice neutral number. Although you might also want `-Infinity`. Probably not relevant here but getting the maximum of `-1` and `-2` with `0` as default would fail.

Comment: @VLAZ dice don't have negative values or am I misunderstanding your statement?

Comment: No, I was just explaining when `-Infinity` is appropriate. In your case it doesn't matter whether you choose `0` or `-Infinity`.

Comment: @VLAZ I see. How do I initialize it in my code? If I just add `a=0;` after the arrow function the rest of the code is unreachable...

Comment: Instead of `null` pass `0`.

Comment: @VLAZ but I pass null by not initializing?.. How do I pass that `0`?..

Comment: Literally just replace that `null` you have in your code with `0`.

Comment: Ohhh, you meant that null, I'm stupid... The error is gone.

Comment: @VLAZ you can put that as an answer and I will accept it.